# Get item from new RecyclerView ListAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

I updated the adapter for RecyclerViev to the new `ListAdapter`, but now I don’t understand how to get the clicked object because the adapter no longer has a list of objects. Previously, I used my custom `ClickListener` interface, which passed to the adapter constructor and next to the viewHolder, through which I received the View and the position of the clicked element

```
interface RecyclerClickListener {

    fun onClick(view: View, position: Int)

    fun onLongClick(view: View, position: Int)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ListAdapter.getItem(position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter.html#getItem(int)) and pass in the clicked position as an integer.

Comment: Thank you, I override getItem function and made it public

Comment: By the way, an alternative way is `youradapter.currentList.get [position]`